# Can I create an interval loop in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, intervals

I'm trying to created a timed loop in an array. This is what I mean..

```
array = [10, 15, 19, 25]
array.each do |e|
    loop do
        ...
    end
end
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
10
#=> then it waits 10 seconds...
15
#=> then it waits 10 seconds...
19
#=> then it waits 10 seconds...
25
```

Is this possible? Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to do something with each array element, but sleep for 10 seconds between iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep x` pauses output for x number of seconds.

So what you're looking for is:

```
array = [10, 15, 19, 25]
array.each do |e|
  puts e
  sleep 10
end
```

Comment: Correct! is there a way i can change  the value of the sleep? besides "e"?

Comment: Yes.  You can put any integer or float as the argument, or variable representing an integer or float.  I edited my original answer when I realized you need 10 seconds each time